# Android ListView particulate row background color change

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom `ListView` where I need to show Available shift in Green `Color` and Unavailable shift in Red. I made a custom adapter in it's `getView()` I am trying to check the value and change the color.

**GetView in Custom Adapter looks like this-**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v==null){
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView1);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


        if(objects.get(position).getprop1().equalsIgnoreCase("Shift -3")) {
            ((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bg);
        }


    holder.textView1.setText(objects.get(position).getprop1());
    holder.textView2.setText(objects.get(position).getprop2());
    return convertView;
}
```

**But the out put I am getting like this -**

[image]

And whenever I am scrolling color are showing in some other value too.

Comment: keep one variable in holder while setting adapter check in getView.

Comment: Can you give an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace you `getView()` by

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView1);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

 /**
  * here check your condtion like this and set color to background no need of for loop
  ***/
        if(objects.get(position).getprop1().equalsIgnoreCase("Shift -3")) {
            ((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bg);
        }else
       {
              // set normal color here
       }


    holder.textView1.setText(objects.get(position).getprop1());
    holder.textView2.setText(objects.get(position).getprop2());
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Actually that loop is for dynamic checking. For testing I put a static value. It's giving the same result as previous...

Answer (score 1):

While you are setting red background for one View you have to set normal background for remaining views by using else case

```
if(objects.get(position).getprop1().equalsIgnoreCase("Shift -3")) {
        ((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bg);
 } else{
   //here set normal background for view.
 }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to View Reuse capability of ListView. If `Shift -3` condition is not met you have to set background of the row to default row color since the row with red background can be reused at any position in list.

```
if (objects.get(position).getprop1().equalsIgnoreCase("Shift -3")) {
            ((RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow))
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bg);
        } else {
            //default bg
            ((RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow))
                    .setBackgroundResource(deafult_bg);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView1);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        if (objects.get(position).getprop1().equalsIgnoreCase("Shift -3")) {
            ((RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bg);
        } else {
            //Update to default color
        }

        holder.textView1.setText(objects.get(position).getprop1());
        holder.textView2.setText(objects.get(position).getprop2());
        return convertView;
    }
```

If the condition is matched set the `RED` color else set the default color.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add else part here as below -

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9 ; i++) {
    if(objects.get(position).getprop1().equalsIgnoreCase("Shift -3")) {
        ((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bg);
    }
    else{
        ((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow)).setB ackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_bg); //your green color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getViewType()`. Try this code (I modified your code for you):

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (objects.get(position).getprop1().equalsIgnoreCase("Shift -3")) ? 1 : 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}        

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView1);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(type == 0) {

            //Set here your regular color
    }else {
        ((RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutSingleRow)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bg);
    }

    holder.textView1.setText(objects.get(position).getprop1());
    holder.textView2.setText(objects.get(position).getprop2());
    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT: I have to explain. If you don't use `getViewType()` method and just if statement like other answers here, then if you have many items in your list (enough for scrolling), your items will change the color dynamically while scrolling.